# if $M$ is a UI - martingale then $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $M$ be a uniformly integrable martingale. Then there exists a random variable $M_{\infty}$ such that $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ in $L^1$.

This is what I have so far:

A UI martingale $M$ is clearly a $L^1$-martingale. Take, for example $\epsilon = 1$. Then, by definition (of UI-martingale), it exists $K_1$ such that $\sup_{t \geq 0} E|M_t|< 1+K_{1}.$ Hence, by the martingale convergence theorem, there exists $M_{\infty} \in L^1$ such that $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ a.s. Now, to show $E|M_t-M_{\infty}| \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, I guess I have to use the dominated convergence theorem but I can't find any bound. If it was $L^2,$ I could use Doob's $L^p$-inequality to find the bound, but we are in $L^1,$ so I don't know how to continue. How can I finish the proof? Is there another way to prove it?

Comment: If $Y_n \to Y$ a.s  and $(Y_n)$ is uniformly integrable then $E|Y_n-Y| \to 0$. Ref. Chung's book.

Comment: Thanks, I know the result is true but is there a proper proof in that book?

Comment: It is amazing that we can take $\epsilon=1$ to claim something that has no apparent connection to $\epsilon$.  (Similarly: "Take $\epsilon=1$.  Then, we know my glasses are in the bathroom.")

Comment: To show @KaviRamaMurthy proposition, we can start by noticing that $X_n = |Y_n - Y|$ is again u.i. then we have $E[X_n] = E[X_n1_{X_n < R}] +  E[X_n1_{X_n \geq R}]$. For all $\epsilon > 0$ and for $R$ big enough, the 2nd term will be lower than $\epsilon/2$ by u.i. And again with that $R$, we have that the first term is lower than $\epsilon/2$ using the probablity convergence for $n$ big enough.

Comment: @Sesame: Thank you. It may be a silly question but, why does $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ (in probability) implies $E[X_n 1_{X_n < R}]< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Rogers and Williams (1st Volume).

We will need the following two results:

> **Proposition 1.** Suppose that $X \in L^1$. Let $\epsilon > 0.$ Then there exists $K$ such that 
>   $$E[|X|;|X|>K] < \epsilon.$$
>
> **Theorem 2.** (Bounded-Convergence Theorem) Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of of random variables, and let $X$ be a random variable. Suppose that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability and that, for some $K \in [0, \infty),$ we have for every $n$ and $\omega,$ that $|X_n(\omega)| \leq K.$ Then
>   $$ E[ |X_n -X |] \rightarrow 0. $$

**Answer to the question:**

A UI martingale $M$ is clearly a $L^1$-martingale. Take, for example $\epsilon = 1$. Then, by definition (of UI-martingale), for all $t \geq 0,$ there exists $K_1$ such that 
$$E|M_t| = E[|M_t|;|M_t|>K_1] + E[|M_t|;|M_t| \leq K_1]= 1 + K_1.$$ 
Hence, 
$\sup_{t \geq 0}E|M_t| \leq 1+ K_1$ and $M$ is a $L^1$-martingale. By the martingale convergence theorem, there exists $M_{\infty} \in L^1$ such that $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ a.s., which implies that $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ in probability.

Next, for $K \in [0,\infty),$ define the functions $g_K: \mathbb R \rightarrow [-K,K]$ as follows:
$$g_K(x):=
\begin{cases}
K \quad \text{ if } x>K; \\ 
x \quad \text{ if } |x| \leq K; \\
-K \quad \text{ if } x<K.
\end{cases}$$

Now, using the family of functions $g_K,$ we will prove that $M_t \rightarrow M_\infty$ in $L^1$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $K$ large enough so 
\begin{align*}
E|g_K(M_t)-M_t| &< \frac{\epsilon}{3}  \tag*{(since M is a UI-martingale)} \\
E|g_K(M_\infty)-M_\infty| &< \frac{\epsilon}{3}  \tag*{(by Proposition 1)} 
\end{align*}

Moreover, note that the functions $g_K$ satisfy that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R,$ $|g_K(y)-g_K(x)| \leq |y-x|.$ Hence, given $K$ from the step before, we have that for all $t \geq 0$
$$|g_K(M_\infty)-g_K(M_t)| \leq |M_\infty-M_t|,$$
which implies that 
$$g_K(M_t) \rightarrow g_K(M_\infty) \text{ a.s. }$$
and also, $g_K(M_t) \rightarrow g_K(M_\infty)$ in probability. Hence, by Theorem 2, for large enough $t$ we have $E|g_K(M_\infty)-g_K(M_t)|< \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$
Therefore, by the triangular inequality
\begin{align*}
E|M_\infty - M_t| &= |M_t - g_K(M_t) + g_K(M_t) - g_K(M_\infty) + g_K(M_\infty) - M_\infty| \\
&\leq |M_t - g_K(M_t)| + |g_K(M_t) - g_K(M_\infty)| + |g_K(M_\infty) - M_\infty| \\
&< \epsilon.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $X_n\to X$ in probability, then there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $X_{n_k}\to X$ a.s. For each positive integer $k$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(|X_n-X|>2^{-k})=0$. So for each $k$, we may find $n_k$ such that $\mathbb P(|X_{n_k}| > 2^{-k})\leqslant 2^{-k}$, and consequently
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_{n_k}-X|>2^{-k})\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}<\infty.
$$
Then by the Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{|X_{n_k}-X|>2^{-k}\right\} \right) = 0,
$$
from which it follows that $X_{n_k}\to X$ a.s.

Since $X_{n_k}\to X$ a.s. we have by Fatou's lemma
$$
\mathbb E[|X|] = \mathbb E\left[\liminf_{k\to\infty}|X_{n_k}|\right]\leqslant \liminf_{k\to\infty} \mathbb E[|X_{n_k}|].
$$

A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ is said to be uniformly integrable if $$\sup_n\lim_{K\to\infty} \mathbb E[|X_n|\mathsf 1_{\{|X_n|>K\}}] = 0.$$ This implies that $\sup_n\mathbb E[|X_n|]<\infty$. Now, we show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any event $E$, 
$$
\mathbb P(E)<\delta\implies \sup_n\mathbb E[|X_n|\mathsf 1_E]<\varepsilon.\tag1
$$
Write $E_n = \{|X_n|>K\}$. Then
$$
\mathbb E[|X_n|\mathsf 1_E = \mathbb E[|X_n|(\mathsf 1_{E\cap E_n}+\mathsf 1_{E\setminus E_n})] \leqslant \mathbb E[|X_n|\mathsf 1_{E_n}] + K\mathbb P(E).
$$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $K>0$ such that $\sup_n\mathbb E[|X_n|\mathsf 1_{E_n}]<\frac\varepsilon2$. Setting $\delta=\frac\varepsilon{2K}$, we see that $(1)$ holds.

Now from $\mathbb E[|X|]\leqslant \liminf_{k\to\infty}\mathbb E[|X_{n_k}|]$ and $(1)$, we have that $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$, i.e. $X\in L^1$. The inequality 
$$
|X_n-X|^r \leqslant 2^r (|X_n|^r +|X|^r),\quad r>0
$$
shows that the sequence $\{|X_n-X|\}$ is uniformly integrable (check this!) and so for for each $\varepsilon>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X_n-X|] & = \mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}] + \mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_{\{|X_n-X|\leqslant\varepsilon\}}]\\
&\leqslant \mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}] + \varepsilon.
\end{align}
Since $\{|X_n-X|\}$ is uniformly integrable,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}] = 0,
$$
from which the result holds.

To answer @UBM's question, we have $$\sup_n \mathbb E[|X_n-X|] \leqslant 2( \sup_n\mathbb E[X_n] + \mathbb E[|X|)<\infty$$ using $r=1$. Pick $M>0$ such that $2( \sup_n\mathbb E[X_n] + \mathbb E[|X|)<M$. Now for each $\varepsilon>0$ we may pick $\delta<\frac\varepsilon M$ such that for any event $E$, $$\mathbb P(E)<\delta\implies \sup_n \mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_E]\leqslant M\mathbb P(E) < M\frac\varepsilon M = \varepsilon.$$ This implies that $\{|X_n-X|\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: Note that we did not need the assumption that the process was a martingale.

Comment: The comment by sesame is almost an entire proof.

Comment: @Math1000: Thank you very much for all the detail but if you didn't assume that $M$ is UI martingale, what claim are you proving exactly?

Comment: Also, what fact did you use to justify that $\mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_{\{|X_n-X|\leqslant\varepsilon\}}]< \varepsilon$?

Comment: I'm a little bit lost because we already knew that $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. and that $X \in L^1.$ It seems that most of your answer is about proving those two facts. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Also, I have seen your hint:$$
|X_n-X|^r \leqslant 2^r (|X_n|^r +|X|^r),\quad r>0
.$$
But I don't know how to use that to prove that  $\{|X_n-X|\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: @UBM I have added the proof that $\{|X_n-X|\}$ is uniformly integrable to my answer; see the edit.

Comment: I began from the start of the proof to show that $X_n\to X$ a.s. and $X\in L^1$ without the assumption that $X$ was a martingale (because, as I showed, it is not needed). This is partly to show that Doob's martingale convergence theorem is not necessary, and also to generalize the result. Doob's martingale convergence theorem has a non-trivial proof involving a so-called "upcrossings lemma" whose proof is more complicated than the one I presented.

Comment: @Math1000: Here $$\mathbb P(E)<\delta\implies \sup_n \mathbb E[|X_n-X|\mathsf 1_E]\leqslant M\mathbb P(E) < M\frac\varepsilon M = \varepsilon,$$ you are proving the whole implication but what we have to prove, is the consequent, so we have to verify this part:$P(E)<\delta$ is true. I don't see this in your proof.

Comment: Math1000: Also, there is no need to use $ |X_n-X|^r \leqslant 2^r (|X_n|^r +|X|^r)$ with $r=1,$  and have a number "2" there. It seems, by looking at what you are doing later, that we just need to use the triangle inequality $|X_n - X| \leq |X| + |X_n|$. Anyway, this is just a minor detail. My previous comment is the important one.

Answer (score 1):

Truncate, using UI, to be able to use DCT.  In more detail, given $\epsilon>0$ use the fact that $(M_n-M_\infty)$ is UI (why?) to choose $K$ so large that $E[|M_n-M_\infty|; |M_n-M_\infty|>K]<\epsilon$. By DCT and pointwise convergence, $\lim_nE[|M_n-M_\infty|; |M_n-M_\infty|\le K]=0$. Therefore $\limsup_nE|M_n-M_\infty|\le\epsilon$.

Comment: So given $\epsilon,$ from the fact that $|M_t-M_{\infty}|$ is UI, we get two things: 1) $E[|M_t-M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty|>K_{\epsilon}] < \frac{\epsilon}{2};$ 2) provides the bound $K_{\epsilon}$ that allows me to use DCT in order to get $E[|M_t-M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty| \leq K_{\epsilon}] <  \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Hence,  $E[|M_t-M_\infty|]=E[|M_t-M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty|>K_{\epsilon}]+E[|M_t-M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty| \leq K_{\epsilon}]< \epsilon.$ Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Almost.  The quantity $E[|M_t-M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty|\le K_\epsilon]$ is small *for large* $t$, because of DCT.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. One last thing, I've just found in Rogers and Williams a proof of this result. They use the fact that $M_t  \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ a.s. implies convergence in probability and they use later what they called the bounded-convergence theorem. Their proof seems unnecessary long comparing with yours. I wonder why. It may be because we haven't proved that $|M_t - M_{\infty}|$ is UI?  Any idea of how to prove $|M_t - M_{\infty}|$ is UI?

Comment: First use Fatou to show that $M_\infty$ is integrable.  Then just use triangle inequality: because $|M_t-M_\infty|\le|M_t|+|M_\infty|$ you have 
$$
\{|M_t-M_\infty|>K\}\subset\{|M_t|>K/2\}\cup\{|M_\infty|>K/2\},
$$
so
$$
E[|M_t-M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty|>K]\le E[|M_t|; |M_t-M_\infty|>K]+E[|M_\infty|; |M_t-M_\infty|>K].
$$
Each term on the right can be made small (uniformly in $t$) by choosing $K$ large: the first because $(M_t)$ is UI, the second because $M_\infty$ is integrable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $E[|M_t - M_{\infty}|;|M_t - M_\infty|>K] \leq E[|M_t - M_{\infty}|;|M_t|>\frac{K}{2}] + E[|M_t - M_{\infty}|;|M_\infty|> \frac{K}{2}]$ instead?

Comment: If what I wrote above is true, then I can't see why $M_t$ being UI implies that $E[|M_t - M_\infty|; |M_t|> \frac{K}{2}] \rightarrow 0.$ I guess the idea was to get as a first term $E[|M_t|; |M_t|> \frac{K}{2}],$ but it's not the case. Do you agree?

Comment: For the first term, because $(M_t)$ is UI, given $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $\Bbb P[A]<\delta$ then $\Bbb E[|M_t|; A]<\epsilon$ for all $t$. The $A$ we will use is $\{|M_t-M_\infty|>K\}$ for large $K$. Maybe the easiest way to proceed is to note that $(M_t-M_\infty)$ is $L^1$ bounded, so there is $C$ such that $\sup_t\Bbb E[|M_t-M_\infty|]\le C$. Then by Markov, $\Bbb P[|M_t-M_\infty|>K]\le \Bbb E[|M_t-M_\infty|]/K\le C/K$, which is smaller than $\delta$ (for all $t$) if $K$ is large enough. The second term is similar.

Comment: Do you agree with what I wrote before?