# Uniformly integrable martingale and $L^1$ convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I want to show the following property:

> Let $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a uniformly integrable martingale, then there exists a random variable $X_\infty \in L^1(\Omega)$ with $X_\infty = \lim_{t \to \infty} X_t$ a.s. and such that $X_t = E[X_\infty \mid \mathscr{F}_t]$.

Here is my proof:

The first statement follows from the fact that all $X_t$ are integrable together with the martingale convergence theorem.
By dominated convergence,
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_\Omega |X_t - X_\infty| dP =  \int_\Omega\lim_{t \to \infty} |X_t - X_\infty| dP =0,
\end{align*}
so $X_t \to X_\infty$ in $L^1$ as well. It remains to show the conditional expectation property. But since for any $A_s \in \mathscr{F}_s$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \int_{A_s} X_t dP = \int_{A_s} X_s dP,
\end{align*}
the property follows from $\int_{A_s} X_t dP \stackrel{t \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_{A_s} X_\infty dP$.

I didn't use the *uniform* integrability...But I can't see my mistake. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: You don't have a dominating random variable so you can't use dominated convergence.  Uniform integrability is the substitute for this.

Comment: Also, the martingale convergence theorem has hypotheses that you need to check - it isn't valid for arbitrary martingales.  Again, uniform integrability provides what you need.

Comment: @NateEldredge True. That was my mistake. In my mind, $X_t$ had a dominating random variable but this is wrong of course... Thanks

Comment: @NateEldredge The hypotheses I know are integrability and right-continuity. Integrability is clear, do you mean the right-continuity?

Comment: What exactly does "integrability" mean?  It can't just mean "each random variable $X_t$ is integrable", because every martingale has that property, and not all of them converge a.s. (consider Brownian motion). One common version of the theorem assumes $L^1$ boundedness, i.e. $\sup_t E|X_t| < \infty$, and you do have that condition satisfied here, thanks to... uniform integrability.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot. Now it is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of $X_{\infty}=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} X_t$ a.s. is because of the martingale convergence theorem (since a uniform martingale is a martingale bounded in $L^1$).

For a proof of $X_t \rightarrow X_{\infty}$ in $L^1$, you can check my answer here: [if $M$ is a UI - martingale then $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494544/if-m-is-a-ui-martingale-then-m-t-rightarrow-m-infty-in-l1/3497440#3497440).

Once we have proved that $X_s \rightarrow X_{\infty}$ in $L^1$ we can prove the last claim.
Let $0 \leq s \leq t$ and let $A \in \mathscr{F}_s.$ Then
\begin{align*}
E[(X_\infty - X_s)1_A] &= E[(X_\infty-X_t+X_t - X_s)1_A] \\
&=E[(X_\infty-X_t)1_A]+E[(X_t-X_s)1_A]\\
&= E[(X_\infty-X_t)1_A] \\
&\leq E[|X_\infty-X_t|] \rightarrow 0 
\end{align*}
as $t \rightarrow \infty.$